# retrieve multiple records from one table

Tags: php

I have a table that displays interests. Each interest has an ID. At the moment the query just brings back one person for one ID. Its basically a filter on the website that sorts the results by interests.

```
$catwhere = " and e.person_id IN (select escint_person from person_interests_person where escint_person = e.person_id and escint_interest = 26) ";
```

I would like it to display the results from multiple interests.

So in my basic logic it would look like this

```
$catwhere = " and e.person_id IN (select escint_person from person_interests_person where escint_person = e.person_id and escint_interest = 26,27,28,29) ";
```

but obviously this doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you already know `IN` clauses, why not use it for `escint_interest` and `26,27,28,29` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `IN` clause in second query.

```
where escint_person = e.person_id and escint_interest IN( 26,27,28,29 )
```